# openlayers3 - Set Node as label for ol.control.FullScreen control

Tags: javascript, css, openlayers-3

I'm trying to set custom span (`<span class="fa fa-expand"></span>`) as the label of the openlayers 3 FullScreen control.

According to the documentation, this should be possible. The documentation states:

> label     string | Node | undefined   experimental
>
> Text label to use for the button. Default is \u2922 (NORTH EAST AND
>   SOUTH WEST ARROW). Instead of text, also a Node (e.g. a span element)
>   can be used.

I tried setting the label like this:

```
let fullScreenControl = new ol.control.FullScreen({
     className: 'fullScreen-button',
     label: '<span class="fa fa-expand"></span>'
});
```

But this seems to html encode my  tag. When I check the generated button in the developer console, it adds `&lt;span&gt;` ...

Can somebody guide me on how to set a "Node" as a label or in general the correct way to set a custom span as the label of the control? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an element object:

```
var mySpan = document.createElement("span");
mySpan.className = "fa fa-expand";

var fullScreenControl = new ol.control.FullScreen({
  className: 'fullScreen-button',
  label: mySpan
});
```